# Do I need to specify the region when instantiating a AWS Helper Class in AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

If I want to call AWS SES from AWS Lambda, I normally write the following when instantiating the AWS Helper Class:

```
var ses = new aws.SES({apiVersion: '2010-12-01', region: 'eu-west-1'});
```

I'm wondering, do I actually need to specify the AWS Region? Or will the AWS SES helper class just run in the region where the AWS Lambda Function is running.

What is the best practice here?  Might I encounter problems later if I omit this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have always specified the region for the sake of being explicit. I went and changed one of my NodeJS Lambda functions using SNS to using an empty constructor instead of providing region and deployed it...it appears to still work. It looks like the service will try to run in the region of the lambda function it is being called from. I imagine the IAM role for the lambda function would play a part as well. As far as best practice, I think it is best to be explicit when possible assuming it isn't creating a ton of overhead/hassle. The problem you risk running into in the future is the use of a resource that isn't in certain regions.

Comment: Agreed: explicit is almost certainly best, even if it works implicitly.  There's an automatic environment variable `process.env.AWS_REGION` containing the region where the Lambda function is actually running, so you could probably be "explicitly implicit" by just passing this value as `region: process.env.AWS_REGION`.

Comment: That's interesting, I never knew about that preset environment variable. And yes, it would definitely be explicitly implicit lol.